# Creating an all-day Google Callendar Event uses normal event reminder defaults

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to make a basic Java program that creates an all-day event when run and want to use my default all-day reminder settings to get around the lack of an API for creating same-day reminders and it's using the default settings for non-all-day events.

I expected that creating an all-day event using the code at the end would use the default all-day event reminders. I've tried adding the snippet directly below this pertaining to setting the default notifications with no change.

```
.setReminders(new Event.Reminders()
        .setUseDefault(true));
```

I've also tried changing the standard event reminders to check if that's updating when a new event is created, and it is, so there's not some weird cache thing happening. The last thing I tried was setting the start and end date to the same day, despite that setting them to be offset by one is the recommended way to to an all-day event it made no difference.

I've attached the event code and a couple of pictures showing my reminder settings and the reminders for an event created with the program.

```
DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(dateFormat.format(today));
DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime(dateFormat.format(tommorow));
Event event = new Event()
        .setSummary("Date " + getDateDifference())
        .setDescription("Date " + getDateDifference())
        .setStart(new EventDateTime()
                .setDate(startDateTime))
        .setEnd(new EventDateTime()
                .setDate(endDateTime));
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdjr9.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHKKQ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an All-day event, you must change `startDateTime` and `endDateTime` to be a String instead of a DateTime object otherwise Google Calendar will treat this event as normal event rather than a All-day event.

The String pattern should be `"YYYY-MM-DD"`.

You can also override the event reminders, if needed, by using this following example:

```
...
EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
    new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60),
    new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
};
Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
    .setUseDefault(false)
    .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
event.setReminders(reminders);
...
```

See [this complete example](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/create-events#metadata) for more information.

---

**EDIT: Adding a working sample based on [Java Calendar Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/java) and [this sample](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/create-events#java)**

- Based on how currently Calendar API handles All-day reminders, the only way to create a same-day reminder is setting a "0 Minutes" override. The reminder will be set to 12AM on the day of the event.
- There is an open Feature Request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761408) to add support for All-day events with same day reminders

#### Complete sample code

```java
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.CalendarScopes;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.EventDateTime;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.EventReminder;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

/* class to demonstarte use of Calendar events list API */
public class CalendarQuickstart {
  /**
   * Application name.
   */
  private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Calendar API Java Quickstart";
  /**
   * Global instance of the JSON factory.
   */
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
  /**
   * Directory to store authorization tokens for this application.
   */
  private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

  /**
   * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
   * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
   */
  private static final List<String> SCOPES =
      Collections.singletonList(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);
  private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

  /**
   * Creates an authorized Credential object.
   *
   * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
   * @return An authorized Credential object.
   * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
   */
  private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT)
      throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = CalendarQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    if (in == null) {
      throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    }
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
        GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
        .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
        .setAccessType("offline")
        .build();
    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    //returns an authorized Credential object.
    return credential;
  }

  public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    Calendar service =
        new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();

    Event event = new Event()
        .setSummary("Google I/O 2015")
        .setLocation("800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103")
        .setDescription("A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.");

    DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2022-11-25");
    EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime().setDate(startDateTime);
    event.setStart(start);
 
    DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2022-11-25");
    EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime().setDate(endDateTime);
    event.setEnd(end);

    EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
        new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(0),
    };
    Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
        .setUseDefault(false)
        .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
    event.setReminders(reminders);

    String calendarId = "primary";
    event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
    System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event.getHtmlLink());
  }
}
```

Comment: I added a toString call on the existing DateTime object and InteliJ showed that neither the EventDateTime().setDate() and EventDateTime().setDateTime() constructors accepted a string. Passing a string instead of an EventDateTime when using or setEnd/Start has the same result of Strings not being accepted. 

Another thing to note is that it is being created as an all day event. The event is at the top of my calendar with an all day event that I would make using the web-UI, just with the wrong reminders.

Comment: Would you know how to set same day reminders? Everything I found said that it couldn't be done yet. That's one of the reasons I'm trying to rely on the default reminders.

Comment: The DateTime constructor I'm referring to is documented on the Google API Java client library documentation [here](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/latest/com/google/api/client/util/DateTime.html#DateTime-java.lang.String-)
Alternatively you could override the reminder as mentioned above. Can you give an example of what you meant by `same day reminders`? When should the event start (DateTime) and what should be the Reminder DateTime?

Comment: I see that DateTime object, but the setStart and setEnd methods require an EventDateTime object and are both rejecting DateTime and String. As for the same day reminders, if I had an event for the 18th of November, I'd like to receive an email at 5 am on the 18th of November, the same day the event takes place. That's something you can set up with the Web UI.

Comment: @NatalieTrinket Got it, my apologies. This is indeed unsupported on API level. I've edited my answer to add more info.